# XML: IF node is BLANK donot show anything in the output

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to trim a XML output and need some advice. My current output is:

```
<Product>
  <ProductUniqueID>16772</ProductUniqueID>
  <Name>Chill Armchair In Leather Px30 Graphite 063 With</Name>
  <ImageUrl>https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/1/0/10157.jpg</ImageUrl>
  <Price>1595.0000</Price>
  <ParentID>20064</ParentID>
  <ProductUrl>https://www.example.com/chill-armchair.html</ProductUrl>
  <CategoryID>Lounge Chairs</CategoryID>
</Product>
```

My question is:

1. Some of my products do not have parent ID, I want to remove node  `<ParentID>20064</ParentID>` when there is no parent ID in a product.
2. I want to remove the spacing in the value of `<CategoryID>Lounge Chairs</CategoryID>` to look like `<CategoryID>LoungeChairs</CategoryID>`

Can you please advise how can I do this? My XML template is,

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
        <Feed>
        <Products>
        <xsl:for-each select="objects/object">
                    <Product>
                         <ProductUniqueID><xsl:value-of select="entity_id"/></ProductUniqueID>
                         <Name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></Name>
                         <ImageUrl><xsl:value-of select="images/image/url"/></ImageUrl>    
                         <Price><xsl:value-of select="price"/></Price>                                                                               
                         <ParentID><xsl:value-of select="parent_id"/></ParentID>
                        <ProductUrl><xsl:text>https://www.example.com/</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="string(parent_item/url_key)"><xsl:value-of select="parent_item/url_key" /></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="url_key" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:text>.html</xsl:text>
                        </ProductUrl>
                         <CategoryID><xsl:value-of select="cats/cat/name"/></CategoryID>
                    </Product>
                   </xsl:for-each>
                   </Products>
                </Feed>
        </xsl:template>
```

Comment: What tool/language/? are you trying to use to do this?

Comment: Product Feed Export Module    http://www.xtento.com/magento-extensions.html

Comment: What is your original XML file? This will help to re-create a reproducible example. Please edit and also please tag this question with `xslt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `xsl:if` test to prevent adding `<ParentID>` to the output XML when the corresponding `object` element doesn't have `parent_id` :

```
<xsl:if test="parent_id">
    <ParentID><xsl:value-of select="parent_id"/></ParentID>
</xsl:if>
```

or if it is possible that `object` element has `parent_id` child without value, and you don't want to output `ParentID` element for this case as well :

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(parent_id)">
    <ParentID><xsl:value-of select="parent_id"/></ParentID>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax will remove the spaces in the string:

```
<CategoryID>
<xsl:value-of select="php:functionString('str_replace',' ','',cats/cat/name)" />
</CategoryID>
```